# Can I pressure can roasted sweet peppers without sugar or vinegar?

Tags: bell-peppers, pressure-canner

I want the naturally sweet flavor of the pepper preserved, so no pickling or added sugar is desired. Can I pressure can sweet fire roasted peppers without sugar or vinegar, or are those required for safety?

Comment: This one seems to be on the borderline:  it looks like a recipe request, but the safety issues for canning (especially low acid foods) seem to be a sepcial case, and there is an issue of if it is even possible under home conditions, which is a legitimate question,  I think.  No sure whether we should close or not.

Comment: I tweaked this a bit, avoiding the taboo "is there a recipe" - I think it's probably okay now. The reason we don't do recipe requests is that they're subjective with many answers, and that doesn't really apply here. You can either do it or not, and there's no subjective variation in a basic canning recipe. (The question could probably be more general, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: This question is roughly the general version: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36625/is-acid-required-when-pressure-canning but I neglected to ask what foods can safely be canned that way.

Answer (score 3):

Peppers are a low acid food, so under home conditions, pressure canning will be required to do so.

See for example:  [NCFHFP recipe for peppers](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/peppers.html).